# Is this use of “on” technically correct?

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot

So I’ve learned that in French it’s common to use “on” in a sentence like “On joue souvent à ce jeu avec mon frère” even if it’s just you and your brother, whereas in english it must be “I” here. This is because if you use “we” in English, it means that you and someone else play with your brother.

I’m wondering if this is grammatically correct in French or if it’s just a common way people speak. Also, is there some type of rule or term for this? I’m interested in reading about it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are grammatical issues with such sentences. *Avec mon frère* is almost equivalent to *moi et mon frère* so it is the way this sentence is generally understood. Of course the context can possibly lead to the alternative meaning you expect in English.

When the phrase is put in apposition like this:

> Avec mon frère, on joue souvent à ce jeu.

there is even less ambiguity.

While the pronoun *on* is quite flexible in French, this usage is also common with *nous*:

> *Avec ma femme, nous montons dans un taxi.*

Using *on* (or *nous*) also makes clear both are equally acting.

Compare:

> *Je m'amuse bien avec mon frère.* I might be the only one having fun.

and

> *On s'amuse bien avec mon frère.* Both of us are having fun.

Finally, beware that many native French people will tell you using *on* instead of *nous* is familiar, lazy or even incorrect while the fact is *on* has essentially replaced *nous* (when *nous* is a first person plural subject) in all language levels of modern spoken French outside very formal ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> "On joue souvent à ce jeu avec mon frère"

is current French, but the use of "on" instead of "nous" is a quite familiar level of language. 
On the literary level, you'd rather say:

> "Nous jouons souvent à ce jeu, mon frère et moi".

Answer (score 0):

Comme le rappelle Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 7e éd., 1959, § 587 a), *l’on* est "l’ancien cas sujet du nom *homme*".

Il s'agit certes d'une forme actuellement considérée comme peu soignée voire impropre (à l'école élémentaire, on reprend assez systématiquement les élèves sur son emploi) lorsqu'elle remplace *nous* (§ 587 *passim*). Lorsqu'on ne sait pas trop de qui l’on parle, *on* remplace peu ou prou *quelqu'un*, comme lorsque le petit ours s'exclame :

> *On* a dormi dans mon lit !

On voit bien que

> Nous avons dormi dans mon lit.

aurait un autre sens...

Mais, pour en revenir à cette première remarque de Grevisse, il est aussi permis de penser qu'un usage *précieux* de ce *l'on* peut être fait, pour peu que l'on sache à qui l'on parle et qu'il connaisse l'histoire de la langue. En particulier lorsque quelqu'un vous dit, d'une façon qu'il ne sait peut-être pas être misanthrope :

> *On* est un con !